# Why does my test function which mocks times never complete in some environments?

Tags: javascript, sinon, chai

I have the following sinon.js/chai.js testing my javascript class.

```html
 describe('tick', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    });
    afterEach(function() {
      this.clock = sinon.restore();
    });
    it('should increase the time waited for all translators', function() {
      let queue = new TranslatorQueue();
      queue.join("translator1");
      this.clock.tick(1000);
      expect(_.head(queue.queue).timeWaiting).to.equal(1);

      queue.join("translator2");
      this.clock.tick(1000);
      expect(_.head(queue.queue).timeWaiting).to.equal(2);
      expect(_.last(queue.queue).timeWaiting).to.equal(1);
    });
  });
```

The test passes fine on my development machine, but the test never completes and appears to go into an infinite loop when attempting to run the test on my staging server. I guess it has something to do with mocking the timer, but how do I go about troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the whole thing of answering your own question by writing it out seems to have worked here.

For future reference, the problem is due to `sinon.useFakeTimers()` being more overreaching than we'd probably like.

Given my code only uses `setInterval()` I was able to get the tests to run by changing the fake call to be

`this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers("setInterval");`

I found the relevant information here: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/484

I'm not 100% sure why it works on my machine but not the server...

Comment: haha I love when this happens. It's called [Rubber Duck Debugging](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/08/18/rubber-duck-debugging/) :-)